# howt o fix protractor that started failing on alerts all of a sudden

Tags: protractor

I have a project that has been running well for a long time now. 
Recently (couple of weeks) the system tests are failing.

After a lot of investigation we concluded that protractor fails to identify and close an alert.

The code that used to work

```
exports.removeFaq = function( index ){
    console.log('deleting item at',index);
    exports.getContent(index).$( '[ng-click="removeFAQ($index)"]').click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
    return browser.sleep(2000);
};
```

is now throwing errors:

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 4.2.0-38-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

and  (using element explorer):

```
> browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : are you sure you want to remove this helper content?}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 4.2.0-38-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

We've tried 
 - `waiting` instead of sleeping.
 - sleeping for a long period
 - ignoring angular.

nothing seems to make any difference whatsoever.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue for a couple of days. Looks like we were on chromedriver 2.21. I updated to the latest version ([2.23](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.23/)) and that seems to have fixed the issue.

The command `webdriver-manager update --chrome` did not work for me so I had to download the zip and extract it to my selenium directory. Under protractor.

Note there is a new protractor major version with updated versions. So updating protractor might fix the problem too.

for protractor version 3.x
You can also modify the file `node_modules/protractor/config.json` with the correct version and then run `webdriver-manager update`

for protractor version 4.x
You should modify the file `./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/config.json` instead.

Comment: that sounds like the solution. I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

How can we say for sure that sleep of `2000ms` is good enough? Exactly for this reason sleeps are not recommended in tests. Instead you can use proper waits and poll for alert. This way you would know that after a certain agreed timeout, alert never showed up and test rightfully failed

```
  //wait maximum up to lets 5s before giving up
  browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 5000); 
  browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I mention in the question that I tried it.. it does not help.